# Email isn't sent on dedicated VPS

Tags: 7, mimemail

I have this code in a custom module used to send an email through Mimemail

```
  if (!isset($message['headers'])) $message['headers'] = array('From' => $from, 'Sender' => variable_get('site_name', 'Drupal'), 'Return-Path' => variable_get('site_mail', ini_get('sendmail_from'))); 
  if (!isset($message['key'])) $message['key'] = array();
    $message = mimemail_prepare_message($message);
    $result = mimemail_mailengine('send', $message);
    if ($result) {
      drupal_set_message(t('Mailing sent sucessfully'));      
    }
    else {
      drupal_set_message(t('Mailing not sent'), 'error');
    }
}
```

It works fine on my local MAMP enviorment, and on my Dreamhost VPS, but when I try to run on Media Temple a dedicated virtual box running Ubuntu, it does not work. I get my error message "Mailing not sent"

drupal_mail_system works fine

Comment: SSH in to your server and run `which sendmail` just to make sure sendmail is installed, and to verify it's location (I think it's `/usr/sbin/sendmail` by default). Then have a look at your php.ini file, and search for `sendmail_path`. If it's commented out, uncomment it and set it to the path you found with the `which` statement. Then restart Apache and see if you still get errors

Comment: Sendmail was not installed, I installed it and am now able to send emails through the command line.  Sending email through my module still does not work though.

Comment: Did you check your php.ini configurations. [This](http://drupal.org/node/404190) article might be useful.